# linux centos 6.7 pip3 install

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pip, centos6

I have a Centos 6.7 distro and I have installed python 3.5 from source.

I wanted then to run `pip3`, but the command was not found.

After researching I tried to install setup tools with ezsetup.

This failed so I downloaded setuptools-20.9.x unzipped this and ran python3.5 easy_install and get the error

```
#ImportError: No module named 'zipimport'
```

Answer (score 9):

First Option:

> Pip is part of Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL), which is a community repository of non-standard packages for the RHEL distribution

1. First, add the EPEL repository [RECOMMENDED]:

`rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm`

2. Update: `yum -y update`
3. Install: `yum -y install python-pip`

Second Option:

We can also use curl and python to download and install Pip;

```
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
```

Then,

```
python get-pip.py
```

Just check by typing: `pip -V`

For reference check [here](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-centos-7/)

Comment: It should be rather _pip -V_

Comment: this way, you install pip for python 2, not 3